# Javascript - Return two outputs through an array.map()

Tags: reactjs, return, components

I have the following return in a react component:

```
render() {
     return(
            <div>
                <div className = "category-name">
                    {categories.map(category =>
                        <p>{category.name}</p>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className = "category-name">
                    {categories.map(category =>
                        <Playlist categoryid={category.id}/>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

This is displaying names of categories and then going through the array of names getting the description from the Playlist component. 
Could someone tell me how I would return the playlists under each name? I tried the following but it just won't work:

```
render() {
  return(
            <div>
                <div className = "category-name">
                    {categories.map(category =>{
                        return (<p>{category.name}</p>,
                            <Playlist categoryid={category.id}/>)
                        }     
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: So you only want to combine both map functions? I guess the second code example throws an error?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the second case? I think you may have to wrap the <p> tag and <Playlist> component within a single wrapper (<div>) if you are getting any error.

Comment: I wasn't getting any error even in the console. The name just wasn't displaying and it was going straight to the component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could used [react fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), using their full syntax `<React.Fragment>` allows you to put a key attribute within them :

```
<div className = "category-name">
    {categories.map(category => {
        return 
            <React.Fragment key={category.id}>
                <p>{category.name}</p>,
                <Playlist categoryid={category.id}/>
            </React.Fragment>
        }   
    )}
</div>
```

The `<React.Fragment>` element will not be rendered in the DOM and allows you to put any elements within them.

Comment: <> </> That's the new thing I have learned from your code. Glad to learn that :)

Comment: <> is shorthand for <React.Fragment>, just in case you are wondering. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Just adding, <></> is good for wrapping components though there is slight difference. React.Fragment also accepts key prop while <></>, Does not. React shows warning when you are rendering components inside loop without key prop.

Comment: Since my answer was lacking a lot of information and was not optimal yet somehow got attention, I updated it with the fragment syntax that allows keys.

Comment: After mocking about with the default "comma" syntax for an hour this saved my day! This works with returning several material-ui TableCell instances

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your elements in map function in some html tag or React.Fragment:

```
render() {
  return(
            <div>
                <div className = "category-name">
                    {categories.map(category => (
                          <div key={category.id}>
                            <p>{category.name}</p>
                            <Playlist categoryid={category.id}/>
                         </div>
                        )
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
```

And please, don't forget to use *key* in your cycles